# CasperJS, Unable to click on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, casperjs

Some how i am unable to click on the modal window's `Pull` button.
Below is the HTML code:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <span class="btn btn-cancel">Cancel</span>
    <span class="btn btn-primary">Pull</span>
</div>
```

and i tried with the following options but still unable to click on it

```
this.evaluate(function () {
    $('#div.modal-footer:nth-child(7) > span:nth-child(2)').click();
});
```

and

```
this.waitForSelector("#div.modal-footer:nth-child(7) > span:nth-child(2)").thenClick("#div.modal-footer:nth-child(7) > span:nth-child(2)");
```

using xpath:

```
casper.click(x("//a[contains(text(), 'Pull')]"));
```

any help will be appreciated

thanks

Comment: remove `#` because `div` is a tag not id

Comment: @Mahi Thanks man. It worked